# Moving files into structured directories based upon their names

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, delimiter

Three main directories are being checked within the script, source, destination, and tertiary.

The script checks the source for a PDF and if the same name and extension does not exist within the tertiary directory, we move the source file to the destination directory. If it exists, then do nothing.

The main problem now is assigning these PDFs to be structured by `name\year\month` within the destination directory:

Destination example:

```
Dest
|
+---Name1
|   |
|   \---Year
|       |
|       \---Month
|
+---Name2
|   |
|   \---Year
|       |
|       \---Month
|
\---Name3
    |
    \---Year
        |
        \---Month
```

The pdf files are all similarly named like so: `NameX_MM-DD-YYYY`

Below is the script I have so far. I was trying to figure out how to use the delimiter and move the files to the proper `NameX` directory, to get baby steps done, but it all just keeps going to the `Name1` directory. The next problem would be to get the dates sorted out properly.

```batch-file
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "src=C:\source"
set "dest=C:\dest"
set "unsigned=C:\unsigned"
set ext=.pdf

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%G IN ('dir /b "%src%\*%ext%"') do (
    for %%i in ("%src%\*%ext%") do (
        IF NOT EXIST "%unsigned%\%%~nxi" (
            move /y "%%~i" "%dest%\%%G%"
            echo "moving 1 file"
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO "file exists"
        )
    )
)

Pause
```

Comment: Restructure your `for` loops; outer loop to process the files: `for %%i in ("%src%\*%ext%") do ...`, inner loop to dissect the file name: `for "tokens=1,2,4 delims=_-" %%G in ("%%~ni") do ...`. your `move` command probably should look like `move "%%~fi" "%dest%\%%G\%%I\%%H\%%~nxi"`

Comment: BTW, I specifically posted an example in your last question to show you correct commands/syntax. Change the `EnableDelayedExpansion` to `EnableExtensions` and `ext=.pdf` to `"ext=.pdf"`.